# uniform convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} {{\sin (x^n)} \over {x^n+n^x}}$ for $x\ge 0$

Tags: real-analysis

I call $f_n(x)={{\sin(x^n)} \over {x^n+n^x}}$ for $x\ge 0$

pointwise convergence: I have pointwise convergence in $[0,1)\cup(1,+\infty)$

uniform  convergence: can I use Weierstrass Majoration test?

If I found a succession $x_n\in [0,1)$so that    $f_n(x_n)$ diverges don't I have uniform convergence in this interval?

my book says there is uniform convergence in $[0,a] \cup [b,+\infty),\quad 0<a<1<b$ why?because is there a problem in 1?

For $x\in [0,1)$ sup is $\frac{sin 1}{1+n}$?

Comment: I must say I don't entirely understand the question. Are you interested in the limit of $f_{n}$ or in the sum of $f_{n}$. Because the pointwise limit of $f_{n}$ is just 0 for all $x\geq0$.

Comment: I'm interested in the pointwise and uniform convergence of the sum.For pointwise it's ok.I don't understand how prove uniform convergence of the sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Uniform convergence.*

$N\in\mathbb{N}_0$

$0\leq x<a<1 :$

$\displaystyle \left|\sum\limits_{n=N+1}^\infty\frac{\sin x^n}{x^n + n^x}\right|\leq \sum\limits_{n=N+1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{x^n + n^x} = \sum\limits_{n=N+1}^\infty\frac{1}{1+x^{-n} n^x}$

$\displaystyle \leq \sum\limits_{n=N+1}^\infty\frac{1}{1 + a^{-n}} \leq \sum\limits_{n=N+1}^\infty a^n = \frac{a^{N+1}}{1-a}< \frac{1}{1-a}$

$1<b<x :$

$\displaystyle \left|\sum\limits_{n=N+1}^\infty\frac{\sin x^n}{x^n + n^x}\right|\leq \sum\limits_{n=N+1}^\infty\frac{1}{x^n + n^x} \leq \sum\limits_{n=N+1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^x} \leq \zeta(x) <\zeta(b)$